# Why is $\mathrm{cf}(\alpha)$ a limit ordinal and $\mathrm{cf}(\alpha)\leq \alpha$?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

Defining the cofinality $\mathrm{cf}(\alpha)$ of a limit ordinal $\alpha$ as the least ordinal number $\theta$ such that $\alpha$ is the limit of an increasing sequence of ordinals of length $\theta$, why must $\mathrm{cf}(\alpha)$ be a limit ordinal and furthermore $\mathrm{cf}(\alpha)\le\alpha$?

Comment: The identity map of $\alpha$ to itself proves $\mathrm{cf}(\alpha)\leq\alpha$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your definition of $\mathrm{cf}(\alpha) = \theta$ should say that $\alpha$ is a limit of an increasing sequence of length $\theta$ of ordinals *less than $\alpha$*. Otherwise every ordinal would have cofinality $1$, since $\alpha$ is the limit of the singleton sequence $\alpha$.

- $\mathrm{cf}(\alpha)$ is a limit ordinal: Suppose $(\beta_\gamma)_{\gamma\in \theta}$ is an increasing sequence of ordinals less than $\alpha$, with $\alpha = \sup_{\gamma\in \theta} \beta_\gamma$. If $\theta = 0$, then $\alpha = \sup \emptyset = 0$, contradicting the fact that $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal. If $\theta = \theta'+1$ is a successor ordinal, then $\alpha = \sup_{\gamma\in \theta} \beta_\gamma = \beta_{\theta'}$, since the sequence has a greatest element. But this contradicts $\beta_{\theta'} < \alpha$. Since $\theta$ is not zero or a successor ordinal, it must be a limit ordinal.

In fact, you can do better than this and prove that $\mathrm{cf}(\alpha)$ is an infinite *cardinal* (in the sense that no ordinal $\beta<\mathrm{cf}(\alpha)$ can be put in bijection with $\mathrm{cf}(\alpha)$). I'll leave this to you as an exercise.

- $\mathrm{cf}(\alpha) \leq \alpha$: We have $\alpha = \sup_{\beta\in \alpha} \beta$, so $\alpha$ is the limit of an increasing sequence of length $\alpha$ of ordinals less than $\alpha$. Since $\mathrm{cf}(\alpha)$ is the least such length, $\mathrm{cf}(\alpha)\leq \alpha$.

Comment: If the limit $\alpha$ of an increasing sequence $a_{\nu<\theta}$ of ordinals of length $\theta$ is defined as the $sup[a_\nu| \nu<\theta]=\bigcup_{\nu<\theta}a_\nu$, why could't it be $\alpha=a_\nu$ for some $\nu<\theta$?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro Part of the definition of cofinality explicitly rules this out. You can only use ordinals strictly less than $\alpha$ in a sequence witnessing the cofinality of $\alpha$. See the first paragraph of my answer.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understan: I read my definition more times and unfortunately I don't see why the ordinals must be less than $\alpha$. Could you explain better?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro I'm saying your definition is wrong.

Comment: This definitions is in "Introduction to Set Theory" by Karel Hrbacek and Thomas Jech.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro Thanks for the reference. The definition in that book is indeed wrong. Textbooks (even very good ones, like Hrbacek and Jech) are not infallible.

Comment: Okay, I believe you; so the correct definition of cofinality would be that the cofinality $cf(\alpha)$ of a limit ordinal $\alpha$ is the least ordinal number $\theta$ such that $\alpha$ is the limit of an increasing sequence $(a_\nu)_{\nu<\theta}$ of ordinals of length $\theta$ such that $a_\nu<\alpha$?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro yes, that's right.